# Is code parameter Value means access_token after Facebook OAuth to my website

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I had made a Facebook APP for authorization of users on my Website, I am using OAuth Method. In My Site i have kept a Feature called "Login in With Facebook", when user clicks he gets redirected to Facebook with link

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=<ID>&redirect_uri=<mysite>&state=<some random hash>&scope=`

This looks fine enough, Now Facebook asks for Allow and when Users clicks allow, I get a URL Back on my site with a Special parameter called `&code=` .. It looks like

`http://mywebsite.com/facebook&code=<some huge Random code>&state=<hash>`

Now, i would like to know what exactly is `code=` parameter value says, is it the access Token of the User because i don't see special parameters like `access_token=`. So can somebody tell me what is code means in OAuth and is it same as Access token. ?? How can i verify it.. Please input your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to exchange that `code` server-side for an `access_token`

There's [specific documentation for this flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode) but essentially you take the code, your app ID, app secret, and the `redirect_uri` you used when opening the dialog initially, and make an API call to exchange the code for an access token

You then use the access token to make API calls on behalf of the user

Comment: Perfect, So i need to check during My Server Side validating the code in order to receive `access_token` ? If let's say an Attacker with malicious intent Tries to OAuth using my Login with Facebook button and gets the `code` in his URL, than can he make Malicious changes like Grabbing OAuth ? I think he must need my client_secret right? :) @igy

Comment: That's one of the advantages of the 'code' flow, without the client secret, the code can't be exchanged for a token and is basically useless